# Render different show pages with category in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements, ruby-on-rails-5

I need render different show pages for my blog posts.

I have 3 different categories : themes, snippets, projects.

Each blog post must related with those three categories.

If anyone click post(assume related category is snippets), it display in different show...etc... It is same for other categories.

How it is possible with conditional statements.

Answer (score 2):

```
you can make routes like:

resources :posts, except:[:show]
get 'posts/:id/cat/:category' , to:'posts#show', as: :show
```

you have to create partial for categories as follows:

> app/views/posts/_themes.html.erb
>
> app/views/posts/_snippets.html.erb
>
> app/views/posts/_projects.html.erb

then in controller's show action.

```
controllers/posts_controller.rb



 

 def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   @category = params[:category]
   ...
 end
```

Then render that category in show page.

views/posts/show.html.erb

```
...
<%= render  '#{@category}'%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one show method and you can render different views conditionally and simple render works for you, you can use below code:

> ## Just render with HTML file name if file is in same controller's view

```
if @post.theme?
  render 'themes'
elsif @post.snippet?
  render 'snippets'
else
  render 'projects'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this, then refactor for avoiding repetition

*categories_controller.rb*

```
def themes
  #@posts = Post.where(category_id: 1)
  ...
  render layout: themes
end

def snippets
  #@posts = Post.where(category_id: 2)
  ...
  render layout: snippets
end

def projects
  #@posts = Post.where(category_id: 3)
  ...
  render layout: snippets
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

*models/post.rb*

```
def category
   @category ||= ... #returns category name
end
```

*controllers/post_controller.rb*

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(id)
  @category = @post.category
  ...
end
```

*views/posts/show.html.erb*

```
...
<%= render "types/#{@category}" %>
...
```

Also you can render specified template from controller if you don't have any common parts for categories

Answer (score 0):

You can use rails partial to achieve this:

to know more about partial refer [Rails Partial](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)

you can create partial for categories as follows:

> app/views/categories/_themes.html.erb
>
> app/views/categories/_snippets.html.erb
>
> app/views/categories/_projects.html.erb

in show page of categories you can modify the show page as follows

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def show
    ...
    render params[:category]
  end
  ...
end
```

Now when you call show page pass a param category which denotes the type of category which you want to show

> if you want to show category snippets then the params will be params[:category] = 'snippets' this will look for partial inside categories view.