# Ruby on Rails - Call both html.erb and js.erb

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

My goal is to call a html.erb and a js.erb file with the same controller but it does only call my html file.
 My js is not called.

 controller/categories_controller.rb

```
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
    @categories = Category.order('name ASC')
    @category = params[:category]
end
```

view/categories/index.html.erb

```
<% @categories.each do |c| %>
  <%= link_to c.name, show_category_path(category: c.id), :id => "btn-filter#{c.id}" %>
<% end %>
```

views/categories/index.js.erb (The problem is here, this file is not called)

```
alert("test");
$("#btn-filter<%=@category%>").attr("class","active");
```

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492362/rails-how-does-the-respond-to-block-work) you can find a clarifier discussion.

Comment: Another interesting discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558477/render-different-show-pages-with-category-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller responds with the format that the request asks for, so, your link asks for HTML, not JS, thus the controller responds with `.html.erb`. If you add a call, like this:

```
<%= link_to c.name, show_category_path(category: c.id), :id => "btn-filter#{c.id}", remote: true %>
```

Your request will ask for JS (because of the `remote: true` attribute) and the controller will respond with `.js.erb`.

Answer (score 1):

```
You should add remote: true option

<% @categories.each do |c| %>
  <%= link_to c.name, show_category_path(category: c.id),remote:true, :id => "btn-filter#{c.id}" %>
<% end %>
```

it will automatically find index.js.erb file.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a **remote: true** attribute to link_to.