# rails 5 - render different links depending on a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 4 links on the page (dresses, skirts, shirts, hats) and I want them to be always different depending on the the page. Let's say we click on hats and the links there would be shirts, dresses, skirts, so the current category we are on won't be displayed.

I found something similar here [1]: [Render different show pages with category in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558477/render-different-show-pages-with-category-in-ruby-on-rails)

But this is not really what I want, as I need to render few links (not one).
My thinking is to create  4 different partials and render 3 links if the params = to the one we don't want to display. Is that a good thinking, or is there any better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide the exact code, so based on what I assume you will approximately have, you could do something like this:

```
# Somewhere in your controller
def index # or any action really
  ...
  @current_category = Category.find(params[:category_name]) " # (Or however you want to refer to your category object.
  @all_categories = Category.all # (Or an array of plain strings, which would then better be set in some before_action hook so it is present in each of your different pages.)
  ...
end

# In your view

(@all_categories - @current_category).each do |category|
  <%= render "categories/link_card", category: category %>
end
```

And then in your partials `categories/_link_card.html.erb` you can have the code for showing the link to any category, using the input variable category to get the exact details of your category. (E.g. name, url).

Comment: thx! This approach is perfect for me, with no conditional statements :D